# How can i initialize a set using loop in c++?

Tags: c++, loops, stl, initialization, set

I need to know can initialize a set using loop and how ?
What should i make in this code ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  set <char>s;
  for (auto it = s.begin(); it != s.end();it++){
      cin >>*it;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the loop condition? At the moment, you are trying to loop over all the elements of the `set`, before you put anything in there. Do you want to loop until the user stops typing (hits ctrl+D)?

Comment: What is the size of a set?

Comment: @ChungHuang The size of a set, you can retrieve with `std::set::size()` although it will return 0 in OPs case.

Comment: First to do is to decide what to do and explain that. For example, initialize the set to what?

Comment: Please, note that `cin >> *it;` cannot work. As the `set` elements are keys they are immutable. `*it` will return a const reference which won't be accepted by the stream input operator. You have to input a separate variable which may then inserted into the set (ignoring the loop condition issue outlined by @BoBTFish which you have to solve also).

Comment: @Scheff, I meant that the size had to be set for s variable.

Comment: Just a guess, but maybe you want to loop over inputs instead of over a set?

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to assume you want to loop over all the user input. Note that the simplest way I have shown will ignore whitespace.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
int main()
{
    std::set<char> s;
    char c; // input from user
    while (std::cin >> c) { // read until end of input
        s.insert(c);
    }

    // do something with s, I guess?
}
```

This: `std:cin >> c` will fail when the user finishes their input, which will terminate the loop. I'll repeat myself: `std::cin >>`  **skips whitespace**. If you want to also read any whitespace characters the user inputs, I can show a way to do that too.

Iterators only let you access items that are **already in** the `std::set` (or other container), and in the case of `std::set` you can't assign to things once they are in there.

Please also note that [`using namespace std;` is widely considered to be bad practice](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/1171191).